# nodejs getting error TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Tags: node.js

My function is

```
generateReport: function() {
          const copyFolder = (src, dest) => {
            return new Promise((res, rej) => {
                fsext.copySync(src, dest, (err, data) => {
                if (err) {
                  return rej(err);
                }
                return res(data);
              });
            });
          };

        const readFile = src => {
            return new Promise((res, rej) => {
                fs.readFile(src, (err, data) => {
                if (err) {
                    return rej(err);
                }
                return res(data);
                });
            });
        };

        copyFolder("./sample/", "./login/sample/" )
        .then(data => {
            return readFile("./sample/Duration_Suite.json", "utf8");
        })
        .then(data => {
        jsonData += data;
        console.log(jsonData)
        })  
    }
```

When I run this function, i am getting error

TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Please let me know where I am doing wrong

Comment: does `fsext.copySync` use a callback?  the "Sync" part of its name indicates it probably doesn't

Comment: even if i give copy also same error @AlwaysLearning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I use a mock version of `copy` and `readFile` the code works fine a long as there are proper callbacks being called. Try running the snippet below.

If you are getting `Cannot read property 'then' of undefined` that means that `CopyFolder` must be returning `undefined`, which doesn't seem possible since it returns a new `Promise`.

Is it likely that you call `generateReport().then(...)` and this is the reason for  the error. Note that `generateReport` itself does not return a promise. It returns nothing at all which means `undefined`. To fix this you should return the promise that `copyFolder` returns. The second code snippet below does that and runs without the error.

**Fist code snippet showing the problem**

```js
const fs = {
  copy: (s,d,cb) => cb(null, `copy data: ${s} ${d}`),
  readFile: (s,cb) => cb(null, `readFile ${s}`)
}
let callcount = 0;

const generateReport = () => {
  const copyFolder = (src, dest) => {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
      fs.copy(src, dest, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
          return rej(err);
        }
        return res(data);
      });
    });
  };

  const readFile = src => {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
      fs.readFile(src, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
          return rej(err);
        }
        return res(data);
      });
    });
  };

  // >>> BAD - no return statement here 
  copyFolder("./sample/", "./login/sample/")
    .then(data => {
      return readFile("./sample/Duration_Suite.json", "utf8");
    })
    .then(data => {
      console.log(`call #${++callcount}: ${data}`);
    });
};
console.log("First call without '.then'");
// first call will output data later since there are timeouts
generateReport();
console.log("Now call with '.then'");
// using .then after will give the error you see
generateReport().then(() => console.log("this fails"));
```

**Second Snippet with Fix**

```js
const fs = {
  copy: (s,d,cb) => cb(null, `copy data: ${s} ${d}`),
  readFile: (s,cb) => cb(null, `readFile ${s}`)
}
let callcount = 0;

const generateReport = () => {
  const copyFolder = (src, dest) => {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
      fs.copy(src, dest, (err, data) => {
        if (err) return rej(err);
        return res(data);
      });
    });
  };

  const readFile = src => {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
      fs.readFile(src, (err, data) => {
        if (err) return rej(err);
        return res(data);
      });
    });
  };

  // >>> FIX - return copyFolder's promise
  return copyFolder("./sample/", "./login/sample/")
    .then(data => readFile("./sample/Duration_Suite.json", "utf8"))
    .then(data => console.log(`call #${++callcount}: ${data}`));
};
console.log("Call with '.then'");
generateReport().then(() => console.log("this worked!"));
console.log("This gets printed before the promise completes");
```

Answer (score 1):

it seems that `fs.readFile` expects callback as third parameter. Try use `utils.promisify`[[link]](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) to promisify it.
Example

```js
        .then(data => {
            const util = require('util');
            const readFilePromise = util.promisify(readFile);
            return readFilePromise("./sample/Duration_Suite.json", "utf8");
        })
```